# Mysql JOIN two nested queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, subquery

In my query below, i am trying to join one result set to another using the `customerNumber` identifier. I want to find each customer's amount ordered and the amount paid. The sql does not execute with no help from Navicat Client

```
SELECT DISTINCT tabl1.customerNumber, 
                tabl1.amountOrdered, tabl2.amountPaid
FROM
(
     SELECT Distinct c.customerNumber, o.orderNumber, 
             SUM(od.quantityOrdered * od.priceEach) amountOrdered
     FROM ClassicModels.Customers c
     INNER JOIN ClassicModels.Orders o 
                ON c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
     INNER JOIN ClassicModels.OrderDetails od 
                ON o.orderNumber = od.orderNumber
     GROUP BY od.orderNumber
     ORDER BY c.customerNumber
) tabl1
INNER JOIN 
(
     SELECT DISTINCT c.customerNumber, p.amount amountPaid
     FROM ClassicModels.Customers c 
     INNER JOIN ClassicModels.Payments p 
                ON c.customerNumber = p.customerNumber
 ) tabl2 ON tabl1.customerNumber = tabl2.customerNumber
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` cannot be part of a subquery w/out `LIMIT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select each customer's amount ordered and amount paid, this much simpler query should work:

```
SELECT o.customerNumber as customerNumber, 
    SUM(od.quantityOrdered * od.priceEach) as amountOrdered, 
    SUM(p.amount) as amountPaid
FROM ClassicModels.Orders o
INNER JOIN ClassicModels.OrderDetails od
    ON o.OrderNumber = od.OrderNumber
LEFT JOIN ClassicModels.Payments p
    ON p.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
GROUP BY o.customerNumber
```

Comment: But i want to also include all customer's who ordered but have not paid. so amountOrdered should also also show records where customer Number is not in payments table. How do i add that to your suggested query

Comment: The order's table does not have quantity ordered, its the OrderDetails that has that information. So an inner join between those two tables is also needed.

Comment: how does this give me customers who have orders but no payments. This query only returns customers with orders and with payments. I want to also show customers with orders regardless of if they paid (total amount ordered per orderNumber) or not and if they havent paid i substitue 0 for amountPaid

Comment: left join will give you records from "left" table that do not have a match in the "right" table. In your case, it will give you records from the Orders/OrderDetails join that have mathiching records in payments table and also that don't have matching records in payments table. If you want to check it, make sure that you have a customer without any payment, but with several orders. You will see NULL for the amountPaid column for that customer.